# Как разбить элемент массива строк на массив из его символов?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, pascal

Есть массивы a и b типа string, где 
`a[1]="hello"; a[2]="woRlD."; a[3]="qejqjekqew";`
Массив b изначально пустой.

Нужно посимвольно разбить n-ный элемент массива и вывести его символы в отдельный массив. Например, если это первый элемент, то нужно, чтобы в массиве b было

`b[1]="h"; b[2]="e"; b[3]="l"; b[4]="l"; b[5]="o";`

Если n = 2, то 
`b[1]="w"; b[2]="o"; b[3]="R"; b[4]="l"; b[5]="D"; b[6]=".";`

Как дополнение нужно разбить все элементы массива на отдельные массивы, при условии, что количество элементов массива a неизвестно.

Comment: Почему у вас массивы индексируются с 1? Это специально так задумано?

Comment: А может, и не надо разбивать? Оба указанных языка позволяют обращаться к отдельным символам строки (синтаксически аналогично массиву)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var 
  a, b: array of string;
  i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(a, 3);
  a[0] := 'hello'; 
  a[1] := 'woRlD.'; 
  a[2] := 'qejqjekqew';

  SetLength(b, Length(a[1]));
  for i := 1 to Length(a[1]) do
    b[i - 1] := a[1][i]; 

end;
```